# How to stop execution in for-comprehension if Option is None using cats IO?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats

If i just use Option in for-comprehension everything goes as expected:

```
val a = Some(1)
val b = None
val c = Some(3)

val r = for {
  aa <- a
  bb <- b
  cc <- c
} yield aa + bb + cc

println(r) // None, because b is None
```

but how to achieve the same behaviour using cats IO?

```
import cats.effect.IO
// in reality this will be a methods with side effect
val a = Some(1)
val b = None
val c = Some(3)

val r = for {
  _ <- IO{println("a"); a}
  _ <- IO{println("b"); b} // want to stop execution here
  _ <- IO{println("c"); c}
} yield ()

r.unsafeRunSync()
```

In result i get `a b c`, but i expect only `a b`.

Is it possible to achieve? Is it a right way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with monad transformers; specifically, you'll want to use [`OptionT[IO, T]`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html#optiont) here:

```
import cats.effect._
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.IO

val a = Some(1)
val b = None
val c = Some(3)

val r = for {
  _ <- OptionT[IO, Int](IO {println("a"); a})
  _ <- OptionT[IO, Int](IO {println("b"); b})
  _ <- OptionT[IO, Int](IO {println("c"); c})
} yield ()

r.value.unsafeRunSync()
```

See it in action [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OpvxoHWTTiKS8cR2u79Ffw).

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what i need!